# Como puedo agrupar el resultado de esta consulta

Tags: sql

Les hago una consulta a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Este es un resumen de una consulta mas grande, pero el problema es el mismo. La consulta que esta abajo me da dos renglones del mismo código y no logro hacer que se sumen los del campo `candidata` y me de un solo registro de cada articulo.

¿saben de que forma podría lograrlo?

```
SELECT 
     sta19.cod_articu,
     sta19.cant_stock,
     count (sta19.cod_articu) as veces
         FROM STA19 
            WHERE sta19.COD_ARTICU = ' 002   01    00'

group by sta19.cod_articu, STA19.CANT_Stock
```

El resultado es:

```
cod_articu         cant_stock          veces
 002   01    00   -2364961.0000000    1
 002   01    00    0.0000000          1
```

Comment: Tienes que agrupar la consulta con **GROUP BY**
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp Para queries simples, también puedes usar DISTINCT():
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! donde esta el campo candidata? cuales son los datos de entrada? si agrupas por stock, entonces no va a dar un solo registro a menos que tengan el mismo stock

Comment: Gracias voy a probar con DISTINCT porque el group by esta en la consulta pero me obliga a poner el campo cant_stock y eso hace que no agrupe.

Answer (score 0):

De tu ejemplo no se puede extraer demasiada información, pero indicas que no se suma y no has utilizado la función `sum`. Si tienes problemas para sumar un conjunto, una solución simple es, envolver el conjunto en una tabla exterior, y sumar en ella.

```
SELECT 
sum(o.veces), sum(o.cant_stock) as suma, o.cod_articu 
from (
SELECT 
     sta19.cod_articu as cod_articu,
     sta19.cant_stock as cant_stock,
     count (sta19.cod_articu) as veces
         FROM STA19 
            WHERE sta19.COD_ARTICU = ' 002   01    00'
group by sta19.cod_articu, STA19.CANT_Stock 
) as o
group by o.cod_articu
```

Comment: Gracias.Mira la consulta completa es esta que detallo debajo.
Pero no se como hacer que agrupe pórque cada campo que agrego me hace que lo ponga en el group by y de ese modo no agrupa si no que desagrupa ya que me hace poner el campo cant_stock, al tener mas de un deposito queda abierta por depósitos.

Comment: SELECT STA11.COD_ARTICU AS [COD ARTICULO],
  STA11.DESCRIPCIO,
  STA11.DESC_ADIC,
       ISNULL (STA11.STOCK_MAXI,0) AS [STOCK MAXIMO],
             CASE WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL THEN 'UNI' ELSE 'UNI' END AS [UNI MED S MAX],
       ISNULL (STA11.STOCK_MINI,0) AS [STOCK MINIMO],
             CASE WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL THEN 'UNI' ELSE 'UNI' END AS [UNI MED S MIN],
       ISNULL (STA11.PTO_PEDIDO,0) AS [PUNTO DE REPOSICIÓN] ,
             CASE WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL THEN 'UNI' ELSE 'UNI' END AS [UNI MED PR],
       ISNULL (STA19.CANT_STOCK,0) AS STOCK,

Comment: CASE WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL THEN 'UNI' ELSE 'UNI' END AS [UNI MED SS],
       ISNULL (SUM ((CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA) - CPA36.CAN_RECIBI),0)  AS [CANTIDAD A REC],
             CASE WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL THEN 'UNI' ELSE 'UNI' END AS [UNI MED A REC],
             CASE WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL THEN 'UNI' ELSE 'UNI' END AS [UNI MED P A]
FROM STA11
LEFT JOIN STA19 ON STA19.COD_ARTICU = STA11.COD_ARTICU
LEFT JOIN CPA36 ON STA11.COD_ARTICU = CPA36.COD_ARTICU
WHERE USA_ESC <> 'B'
GROUP BY STA19.CANT_STOCK, STA11.COD_ARTICU,

Comment: STA19.COD_ARTICU, STA11.DESCRIPCIO, STA11.STOCK_MAXI, STA11.STOCK_MINI, STA11.PTO_PEDIDO, STA11.DESC_ADIC
ORDER BY STA19.CANT_STOCK ASC

PErdon por tantos comentarios pero no entraba de otro modo....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STA11.COD_ARTICU AS [COD ARTICULO], 
       STA11.DESCRIPCIO, 
       STA11.DESC_ADIC, 
       ISNULL(STA11.STOCK_MAXI, 0) AS [STOCK MAXIMO],
       CASE
           WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'UNI'
           ELSE 'UNI'
       END AS [UNI MED S MAX], /* SIEMPRE ES UNI, PUEDES SUSTITUIR EL CASE POR UN LITERAL ,'UNI' AS [UNI MED S MAX], */
       ISNULL(STA11.STOCK_MINI, 0) AS [STOCK MINIMO],
       CASE
           WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'UNI'
           ELSE 'UNI'
       END AS [UNI MED S MIN],  /* SIEMPRE ES UNI, PUEDES SUSTITUIR EL CASE POR UN LITERAL */
       ISNULL(STA11.PTO_PEDIDO, 0) AS [PUNTO DE REPOSICIÓN],
       CASE
           WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'UNI'
           ELSE 'UNI'
       END AS [UNI MED PR],  /* SIEMPRE ES UNI, PUEDES SUSTITUIR EL CASE POR UN LITERAL */
       ISNULL(SUM(STA19.CANT_STOCK), 0) AS STOCK, /*SUMA*/
       CASE
           WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'UNI'
           ELSE 'UNI'
       END AS [UNI MED SS], /* SIEMPRE ES UNI, PUEDES SUSTITUIR EL CASE POR UN LITERAL */
       ISNULL(SUM((CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA) - CPA36.CAN_RECIBI), 0) AS [CANTIDAD A REC],
       CASE
           WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'UNI'
           ELSE 'UNI'
       END AS [UNI MED A REC], /* SIEMPRE ES UNI, PUEDES SUSTITUIR EL CASE POR UN LITERAL */
       CASE
           WHEN STA11.COD_ARTICU IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'UNI'
           ELSE 'UNI'
       END AS [UNI MED P A] /* SIEMPRE ES UNI, PUEDES SUSTITUIR EL CASE POR UN LITERAL */
FROM STA11
     LEFT JOIN STA19 ON STA19.COD_ARTICU = STA11.COD_ARTICU
     LEFT JOIN CPA36 ON STA11.COD_ARTICU = CPA36.COD_ARTICU
   WHERE USA_ESC <> 'B' 
GROUP BY 
/*SUMA EL STOCK DE EL ALMACEN POR TANTO NO AGRUPES POR EL */
         STA11.COD_ARTICU, 
         STA19.COD_ARTICU, 
         STA11.DESCRIPCIO, 
         STA11.STOCK_MAXI, 
         STA11.STOCK_MINI, 
         STA11.PTO_PEDIDO, 
         STA11.DESC_ADIC
ORDER BY STOCK ASC;
/* ORDER BY UTILIZA EL ALIAS DE COLUMNA NO EL CAMPO*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Un `SELECT` puede utilizar múltiples funciones agregadas tales como: SUM, COUNT, MAX, AVG. Los campos que se utilizan dentro de estas funciones no van en el  `GROUP BY` asi que prueba esto:

```
SELECT 
     sta19.cod_articu,
     sum (sta19.cant_stock) AS cantidad,
     count (sta19.cod_articu) as veces
         FROM STA19 
            WHERE sta19.COD_ARTICU = ' 002   01    00'

group by sta19.cod_articu
```